# RSS Parser Fatal Exception AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rss

I am Android Beginner I am trying to parse an RSS feed and store the texts from the title and link tags.

I am using the XMLPullParser and I am trying to  extract only the data between the item tags.

The AsycTask is throwing a runtime error and I cant figure out what could be causing it.

Any help at all would be really appreciated.

Code

```
package com.example.simplerssreader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    List<String> headlines;
    List<String>links;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     // Initializing instance variables
        headlines = new ArrayList<String>();
        links = new ArrayList<String>();


      new  XmlParserTask().execute("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");


           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

            setListAdapter(adapter);


    }



    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
       try {
           return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
         }
    }





       public class  XmlParserTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>
       {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try{
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myParser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();
                    myParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myParser.setInput(stream, null);

                    int event;
                    String text=null;

                    boolean insideItem =false;


                        event = myParser.getEventType();

                       while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                       if(myParser.getName().equals("item"))
                       {
                           insideItem = true;
                       }

                       String name=myParser.getName();

                       switch (event){
                          case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        break;
                          case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                           text = myParser.getText();
                          break;
                          case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                           if(name.equals("title") ){

                               if(insideItem == true){
                                headlines.add(text);
                               }
                             }
                             else if(name.equals("link") ){ 
                                 if(insideItem==true)
                                 {
                                links.add(text);
                                 }
                             }

                             else{
                             }
                             break;


                       }
                       if(myParser.getName().equals("item"))
                       {
                           insideItem = false;
                       }
                       event = myParser.next();

    }


        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;

        }

       }


}
```

Logcat

```
04-29 16:52:02.140: D/dalvikvm(1270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 5% free 2948K/3092K, paused 49ms, total 50ms
04-29 16:52:02.140: I/dalvikvm-heap(1270): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.562MB for 635812-byte allocation
04-29 16:52:02.250: D/dalvikvm(1270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3566K/3716K, paused 58ms, total 58ms
04-29 16:52:02.560: I/Choreographer(1270): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-29 16:52:02.650: D/gralloc_goldfish(1270): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-29 16:52:04.880: W/dalvikvm(1270): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a5dba8)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): Process: com.example.simplerssreader, PID: 1270
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.example.simplerssreader.MainActivity$XmlParserTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:99)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at com.example.simplerssreader.MainActivity$XmlParserTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-29 16:52:04.910: E/AndroidRuntime(1270):     ... 4 more
04-29 16:57:05.340: I/Process(1270): Sending signal. PID: 1270 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What's the line 99 of your MainActivity file?

Comment: This sets the insideItem to true if it is in the item tag so then checks if it is true before extracting the data

Comment: just a suggestion, there are several RSS formats ot there and several variations of them, you can use the Google Feed API that reads most of the formats and parses them on saner format https://developers.google.com/feed/

Answer (score 0):

> public abstract String getName ()
>
> For START_TAG or END_TAG events, the (local) name of the current element is returned when namespaces are enabled. When namespace processing is disabled, the raw name is returned. For ENTITY_REF events, the entity name is returned. If the current event is not START_TAG, END_TAG, or ENTITY_REF, null is returned.

So definitely, you're not in a `START_TAG` nor a `END_TAG`. As you haven't started processing, my guess is that you're on the `START_DOCUMENT` tag, so that's why it's throwing that exception. You have to check in which state you are to avoid this Exception.